# Почему не передаются данные в переменные методом GET?

Tags: php

http://localhost/php/test.php?a=77&b=10

В документе прописано:

```
<?php 
    echo $a;
    $c=$a+$b;
    echo"<br>Сумма переменных переданную через адресную строку: $c";
?>
```

А вывод на экран такой:

> Сумма переменных переданных через адресную строку: 0

Comment: не передаю**тс**я  
попроб**о**вал

Answer (score 3):

Вы, наверное, нашли этот пример в какой-нибудь старой книге или руководстве.

Раньше в PHP возможно было использовать так называемое "регистрирование переменных EGPCS (Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server) в качестве глобальных переменных". Однако это порождало ужасные дыры в безопасности, и начиная с PHP 4.2.0 опцию Register_Globals, которая позволяла так писать, отключили. В версии PHP 5.3.0 она была помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ и УДАЛЕНА в PHP 5.4.0.

Подробнее можете почитать тут: [Использование глобальных переменных (Register_Globals)](https://php.net/manual/ru/security.globals.php)

Используйте стандартные массивы $_GET, $_POST и $_REQUEST для получения данных.

Answer (score 2):

Принимаемые переменные методом GET имеют вид `$_GET["name"]`, то есть в вашем случае `echo $_GET["a"];` выведет 77, дальше, думаю, сами...

Comment: Правильно!) я как раз так и попробывал) спасибо..